# convert rows to column in entity framwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, entity-framework-4

how can i convert rows to column in entity framework!?

i have a result like this:

[image: the result my code]

and i want this result:

[image: i want this result]

my entity code i this :

```
(from loanPerson in context.LoanPersons.AsParallel()
                  join warranter in context.Warranters.AsParallel() on loanPerson.Id equals warranter.LoanPersonId
                  where loanPerson.Id == 84829
                  select new
                  {
                      loanPersonId = loanPerson.Id,
                      waranterId = warranter.WarranterPersonID,
                  }).ToList();
```

and number of the row always less than 3 and i want to have 3 column.

please let me know your answer. 
tanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you plan to define an anonymous type with a variable number of properties?

Comment: @mjwills the number of variable is 3 and int

Comment: Look at the many questions on "LINQ + pivot" and pick one that you can mark as duplicate of yours.

Comment: By the way: you really have to remove those `AsParallel()` calls from your query. Contrary to their purpose they hit performance badly because they pull *all* data from `LoanPersons` and `Warranters` into memory first before filtering, joining and projecting. By removing them you'll have one efficient SQL query that runs in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the only one row, where `waranterIds` will contain, at this particular case, three `WarranterPersonID` values, also this field is of `List<int>` type, because it's quantity not known at compile time:

```
var answer = (from loanPerson in context.LoanPersons.Where(x => x.Id == 84829)
              join warranter in context.Warranters 
              on loanPerson.Id equals warranter.LoanPersonId
              group warranter by loanPerson.Id into sub
              select new
              {
                 loanPersonId = sub.Key,
                 waranterIds = sub.Select(x => x.LoanPersonId).ToList()

                 //if you sure, that quantity equals 3, 
                 //you can write this code instead of waranterIds:
                 //zamen1 = sub.Select(x => x.LoanPersonId).First(),
                 //zamen2 = sub.Select(x => x.LoanPersonId).Skip(1).First(),
                 //zamen3 = sub.Select(x => x.LoanPersonId).Skip(2).First()
              }).ToList();
```